# POST method does not work

Tags: php, android, jsonobject, jsonarray

Hola tengo un login de php que conecta con Android, me da el tipico eror ese de

> `org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be
>   converted to JSONObject.`

Creo que es el php porque cuando trato de hacer post en postman me dice que faltan parametros. Sin el iiset me dice `Notice: Undefined variable`

```
<?php
include "db/conexionDB.php";
$response = array();
if(isset($_POST['correo'])&&isset($_POST['clave'])){
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $post_password = $_POST['clave'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT idusuario, clave FROM usuarios WHERE correo = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$correo);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($idusuario, $db_password);
    $stmt->fetch();
    if(password_verify($post_password, $db_password)){
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['message'] = "Login Successful!";
        $response['correo'] = $correo;
        $response['idusuario'] = $idusuario;
    } else{
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['message'] = "Invalid Email or Password";
    }
} else {
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "Insufficient Parameters";
}
echo json_encode($response);    
?>
```

Comment: ya lo cambie al español

Comment: EL problema es que tu login tiene un error, revisa que error muestra la página ya que cuando se intenta parsear no es un JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno por el error que te sale veo varios escenarios posibles que te esten causando problemas, asegurate de agregar las cabeceras correctas en php:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Del lado de tu cliente en este caso Android no sé si estas intentando parsear la respuesta que te devuelve php, en este caso no sería necesario ya que es un objeto json no un string, por lo que te aconsejo imprimir la respuesta que obtienes antes de intentar manipularla.

En postman también es muy probable que no estes enviando la inforamción correctamente por eso no llegan al backend, asegurate que los parámetros vayan de esta forma cuando es por post.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Prueba hacer esto antes al principio de tu script de php para asegurarte de que las variables llegan correctamente.

```
var_dump($_POST); die(); echo "<pre>";
```

Otra cosa que ayudaría mucho es que mostraras el error completo, ya que después del undefined variable te dice que variables es la que causa el problema, en este caso sospecho que pudiera ser $conn la que este causando el problema ya que no la veo definida previamente.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT idusuario, clave FROM usuarios WHERE correo = ?");
```

Por último no olvides cerrar tu conexión.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahora sí me recibe los datos pero me sale el error de que son incorrectos aunque no estén buenos. Tú qué crees que podría ser?

Comment: Qué error te sale?

Comment: Me sale el error de que clave y correo son invalidos aunque los tenga bien. Ese es el codigo que tengo :https://pastebin.com/uacZFM0g

Comment: proporciona el código de tu función password_verify() es ahí donde te manda el error?

Comment: Sip pero no tengo la version de PHP que lo incluye y cuando trato de cambiarlo no funciona x eso lo trate de hacer mas manual